# NullPointerException after authentication

Tags: spring, spring-security

```
public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    User user;

    @Autowired
    JdbcUserDAO jdbcUserDao;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAuthenticationProvider.class);

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        // You can get the password here
        log.info("Before null !!!");
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
/*@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)*/ 
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    MyAuthenticationProvider myAuthenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        /* builder.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");*/
        builder.authenticationProvider(myAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .requestCache()
            .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }
}
```

Whenever I do authentication using curl, I get `NullPointerException` in `MyAuthenticationProvider` at `getCredentials()` method. How many times it enters into authenticate methods , I have put the logs to ensure it gets successful , it also prints the proper credentials whenever I do curl.

Comment: Please add a language tag.  Java?

Comment: if `authentication.getCredentials()` is null, calling `toString()` will definitely result in a null pointer. Verify the otput from `authentication.getCredentials()`.

Comment: But it verifies for the first time , why does it again goes for the verification